# How can I roll up rate-of-return into net asset value in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, calculated-columns

Given the starting value `@pStartingValue` and a table which contains `rorDate` and `ror` what is the most efficient way to get the NAV at each date using just TSQL?

This mathematically trivial, and simple in code. I have a naive SQL implementation currently that relies on cursors.

On the first date, the NAV is @pStartingValue * ror
On every subsequent date, it's the previously calculated nav * ror **or** it's @pStartingValue * every previous ror

How would you efficiently do this only in MSSQL2005+?

```
DECLARE @rorDate DATE
DECLARE @getDate CURSOR
DECLARE @lastNAV as DECIMAL(19,7)
DECLARE @datedRoR as float
DECLARE @NAVTotals TABLE
(
  NAV DECIMAL(19,7),
  navDate DATE
)


SET @lastNAV = 100

SET @getDate = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT 
        p.[DATE]
    FROM 
        performance p 
    ORDER BY 
        p.[DATE]

OPEN @getDate
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getDate INTO @rorDate
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

SELECT 
    @datedRoR = b.finalNetReturn 
FROM 
    performance b 
WHERE 
    b.date = @rorDate

INSERT INTO @NAVTotals (NAV, navDate)
  VALUES (@lastNAV * (1 + @datedRoR), @rorDate)

SELECT 
    @lastNAV = c.NAV 
FROM 
    @NAVTotals c 
WHERE 
    c.navDate = @rorDate  


FETCH NEXT
FROM @getDate INTO @rorDate
END
CLOSE @getDate
DEALLOCATE @getDate

select * from @NAVTotals
```

Comment: Show us your cursor approach and your likely to get a much better result that matches your expected output.

Comment: @RThomas I have added my cursor implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do some testing to see if the performance improves but this is a way to do that same thing without using a cursor.  It's untested so you'll want to make sure to test it.  I also cast `b.finalNetReturn` as a float, if it's already a float you can remove that part.

```
DECLARE @lastNAV as DECIMAL(19,7)

SET @lastNAV = 100    

DECLARE @NAVTotals TABLE
(
  NAV DECIMAL(19,7),
  navDate DATE
);

INSERT INTO @NAVTotals (navDate) 
   SELECT [DATE]
    FROM performance
    ORDER BY [DATE] ASC;

UPDATE NT
SET @lastNAV = Nav = (@lastNAV * (1.0 +
 (Cast((SELECT b.finalNetReturn 
        FROM performance b 
        WHERE b.date = NT.navDate) AS FLOAT)))) 
FROM @NAVTotals NT;

SELECT * FROM @NAVTotals ORDER BY navDate;
```

---

By dropping the lastNAV variable into the update statement you can update both.  It works similar to:

```
a = a + 1
```

There is an [example of this same approach here](http://geekswithblogs.net/Rhames/archive/2008/10/28/calculating-running-totals-in-sql-server-2005---the-optimal.aspx).  Including some good numbers that compare the efficiency of the approach to other approaches such as cursors.

Comment: I don't see how @lastNAV gets set? This doesn't seem like it will work.

Comment: Sorry, I was typing faster than I was thinking.  Take a look now.  I think this should work - it's an approach I've used in the past for running total type operations.  If I've misunderstood what your trying to do let me know.

Comment: Doesn't execute, must declare scalar variable @NAVTotals, you can't use the table reference as a scalar in your subquery.

Comment: You'll have to use a table alias - and with an update you have to be even trickier. Fixed answer (again).

Comment: Your solution works, but not for my *actual* implementation. I thought I would simplify it for posting it here, but in reality I have more than one asset in the table (related by assetID) to a "StartingAssetValue" table. I do think, though, that you answered the question asked!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm not understanding it correctly, but you don't even need a stored proc to achieve this.

```
SELECT p.[DATE] AS navDate
     , @pStartingValue * PRODUCT(1 + b.finalNetReturn) AS NAV
  FROM performance p
 INNER JOIN performance b
    ON b.[DATE] <= p.[DATE]
 GROUP BY p.[DATE]
 ORDER BY p.[DATE]
```

However, there are a few "wierdness" that I don't grasp.

1. How come there is no range limit for p.[DATE]?
2. Does the "performance" table really have only one asset?

Comment: Your query won't work, it simply multiplies startingvalue by each ror, but doesn't accumulate them. And no, the table has  multiple assets but I access them one at a time so I can append the 'WHERE' clause as needed. I just removed it from the sample.

Comment: Did you run it? PRODUCT is an aggregate function. Also take note on the alias p or b.

Comment: there is no `PRODUCT` aggregate function in MSSQL.